# Reduce variable name length

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am using code below, the session variables are declarated in *Common* class and under *SessionVariables* struct.

The session variable name become pretty long to use, do you have any idea how variable names can be minimized in my situation? Can I use variable name like SessionVariables.IsLogout without including class name?

Session[Common.SessionVariables.IsLogout]

```
public class Common
{
    public struct SessionVariables
    {
        public static string IsLogout = "IsLogout";
    }
}
```

Comment: Long session variables can be considered a good thing!  They describe their purpose and are self documenting, it beats using names that are some arbitrary value such as s,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `using` [alias directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx). You will then be able to access the variable as `SV.IsLogout` as in this example:

```
namespace Foo
{
    using SV = Common.SessionVariables;

    public class Common
    {
        public struct SessionVariables
        {
            public static string IsLogout = "IsLogout";
        }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public void Bar()
        {
            string test = SV.IsLogout;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea but that I do not like that using SV = Common.SessionVariables; must be put in every code file. Is it possible to register globally for all code files in project?

Comment: @Tomas: Unfortunately not. But I don't think that's a dealbreaker because a) you only do it once per file, b) you can work the long way even if you don't do it, so it doesn't depend on any special trick the dev must be aware of, c) it's purely opt-in

Comment: I mark your answer as correct because it is really shortest solution, no need to write any additional code, easy and clean.

Answer (score 2):

Create extension methods for the `HttpSessionState` class.

```
public static class HttpSessionStateExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLoggedOut(this HttpSessionState instance)
    {
        return instance[Common.SessionVariables.IsLogout] == true.ToString();
    }
    public static bool SetIsLoggedOut(this HttpSessionState instance, bool value)
    {
        instance[Common.SessionVariables.IsLogout] = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

which allows you to use (typed and everything):

```
session.IsLoggedOut();

session.SetIsLoggedOut(false);
```

Comment: Could you show how to assign value to session? Your code only allow to read from session.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be to inherit your class from the Common class. Then you can directly refer to the variable as SessionVariables.IsLogout.

Answer (score 1):

This is just one way of making it shorter

```
 public static class Account
    {
        public static int UserID
        {
            get { return Session[SessionVariables.UserID]; }
            set { Session[SessionVariables.UserID] = value; }
        }

        // .... and so on
    }
```

you can use them like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Write(Account.UserID);
}
```

It's a lot shorter to use rather than using Session[Sessionvariables.UserID] all the time.

My 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

You could create a "shortcut class" like:

```
public class SesVar
{
    public Common.SessionVariables IsLogout
    {
        get
        {
            return Common.SessionVariables.IsLogout;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you cah do `Session[SesVar.IsLogout]`.

But personally I wouldn't do that, because its not good for the readability of your code and IntelliSense does most of the typing for you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a base class with properties such as:

```
class PageWithProperties
{
    public bool IsLogout { get{ return (bool)Session["IsLogout"] }
                           set { Session["IsLogout"] = value; } }
}

class PageClass : PageWithProperties
{
     void PageClassMethod()
     {
         if(IsLogout)
         {

         }
     }
}
```